# Symfony 2.8 loading a wrong entity instance to controller

Tags: routes, symfony-2.8

I have following symfony 2.8 controller

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a productVariation entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{productId}/variation/{variationId}", name="productvariation_show")
 * @ParamConverter("variation", class="AppBundle:ProductVariation", options={"id" = "variationId"})
 * @ParamConverter("product", class="AppBundle:Product", options={"productId" = "productId"})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showVariationAction(Product $product,ProductVariation $productVariation)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createVariationDeleteForm($product,$productVariation);

    dump($product);
    dump($productVariation);
  /.../
}
```

The problem is that auto injected object instance of `ProductVariation` is wrong.

Further details

- `{productId}` parameter in the route is working correctly, which means if I use `1` as `{productId}` the corresponding `Product`object is correctly given to me through 1st parameter (`Product $product`).
- But `{variationId}` parameter is not loading correctly. It's always loading one particular `ProductVariation` object regardless of what is being passed to `{variationId}`(Take `../1/variation/1` and `../1/variation/2` and `../1/variation/3` are all loading  `ProductVariation` object with `id-2`).
- Just found out that auto loaded `ProductVariation` object depends on what's being passed to `{productId}`. It seems that auto injected `ProductVariation` object is always the one with lowest `id` value for given
  `Product` (There is one to many relationship between product and product variation)
- Already tried the following code with same problem

  ```
  /**
   * Finds and displays a productVariation entity.
   * @Route("/{productId}/variation/{Id}", name="productvariation_show")
   * @Method("GET")
   */
  public function showVariationAction(Product $product,ProductVariation $productVariation){
   /...
  ```

Code snippets for Entities are as follows

```
class Product{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

private $productId;
/../
public function getProductId(){
    return $this->productId;
}
/..

class ProductVariation{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
/../
public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}
 /..
```

I cannot exactly understand this behavior, I want to load whatever `Product` or `ProductVariation` objects that are passed through route parameters

Answer (score 0):

When using the "identifier" of an entity in a route, you do not need the @ParamConverter annotation since the fetching of an entity by its id is the default behaviour for the converter.

So the action can be as follow:

```
/**
 * Create variation delete form with product and the variation. 
 * (or so the intent seems to be looking at the 'createVariationDeleteForm' being called)
 *
 * @Route("/{product}/variation/{productVariation}", name="product_variation_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * 
 * @param Product $product
 * @param ProductVariation $productVariation
 */
public function showVariationAction(Product $product, ProductVariation $productVariation)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createVariationDeleteForm($product,$productVariation);

    dump($product);
    dump($productVariation);
}
```

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter